# Lead auto convert

Tags: trigger, lead-conversion

I tried to convert lead in to account,contact,opportunity at a same time using trigger.

Is it possible to convert three objects at a time.If it is possible send me some trigger regarding this.

I tried one code..I don't know whether it is correct or not.
This is my code which I tried...

```
trigger LeadUpdate on Lead (after update)
{
   Set<Id>leadids=new Set<Id>();
   List<Account>accupdate=new list<Account>();
   for(Lead ld:trigger.new)
   {
      if(ld.Isconverted && ld.Status=='Qualified') 
      {
         account a=new account();
         a.Id=ld.Id;
         a.name=ld.Name;
         accupdate.add(a);
         system.debug('b:'+a);
      }
   }
   system.debug('a:'+accupdate);
}
```

If it is wrong give me suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please look at [ask] on getting the most from the Community. You can start with indenting your code (use [edit] ).

Comment: Converting a Lead into Account, Contact & Opportunity is a standard feature. What is the requirement that has to be achieved via trigger.